# Ajax doesn't display anything url

Tags: ajax, jquery

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class ="click"> Click me <div>
<div class = "file"></div>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".click").click(function(){

        $.ajax({

            beforeSend: function(){
            $(".file").html('<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">' )
            },
            url: 'a.txt',
            type: "GET",
            data: ({

            "id" :  0       
            }),                 
            success:function(results){
                console.log("inside success");
                $(".file").html('results');
            }   

        });

    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here problem is that success:function never calls up...I am not getting any results..just the spinner...my `a.txt` file is in same folder as this html is. the content of a.txt is `<br> Hello world <br>`.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: actually not..the firebug doesn't even get into this line

Comment: Bring up your console (Cmd+j) to see if there are any errors. You may also need to provide an absolute path to your file, ie. http://example.com/a.txt

Comment: Check the firebug's Net tab and see what happens.

Comment: Check the network / requests tab are you making a request to `a.txt`? What status code does your request return 404?

Comment: firebug net tab shows only the time to load jquery library..ther is no mentioning of this ajax call

Comment: Then you don't hit your success because you never even make your request. Step 1 in debugging. So now you are trying to figure out why you don't make a request at all. Try a simpler demo from the http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and see if you get that working.

Comment: i thought i have some syntax error or i am missing some value..but actually i can't figure out this.

Comment: try data:"id=0" instead of the object ...unh...and add a semicolon in the beforeSend function....there's missing one (which shouldn't be the cause....but you never know...)

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem but close this div tag properly <div class ="click"> Click me </div>

Comment: nothing helps guys (((

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".click").click(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url: 'a.txt',
        type: "get",
        data: "id=" + 0,                 
        success:function(results){
            console.log("inside success");
            $(".file").html(results);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(".file").html('<img src="a.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">' );
        }

    });

});
```

...i'd be surprised if that wouldn't work... tough having an class selector used with .html() might result in horrible erros when the class "file" is used more than once

Comment: i tried this one too....but you know what nothing happens..this success callback is never called...can you try the same code in your machine and update with results..may be some machine specific issue with me though

Comment: if you wait two hours, yes...i have to catch a bus :(

Comment: so, i did get distracted yesterday, sorry. i tried it now and it works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/ (works, it 404's, but the request is being send)